# Seamless live broadcast to youtube

Tags: javascript, web, webrtc, youtube-livestreaming-api, hangouts-api

I want to provide live broadcast functionality to users of my website using Youtube service but I am not sure if it is possible in a way I want or not.

That's what I want:

1. User clicks on start broadcast button
2. On server side, I insert `Broadcast event` and `Live Stream` for that user using `Youtube Data API`. **(I don't want to ask user to login into his/her youtube account for that)**
3. Send some identifier of broadcast and streams back to client browser.
4. Start sending audio/video (and possibly screen sharing) feed to that live broadcast, preferrably using WebRTC.

Is above scenario possible? If so, what kind of effort should be required to make it work with WebRTC? If, it is not possible with WebRTC, then do I need to develop android Application, browser extension etc? What are my options?

Comment: You should also read the legal stuff: https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

Comment: When you say server side, what is the current server you are using? Also the above functionality can be implemented using either WebRTC Gateways or [FreeSWITCH](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/FreeSWITCH+1.6+Video).

Comment: I am using C# MVC for server.

Comment: What is the role of the C# MVC Server? Like is the signalling server? In case you are routing the media over the C# server then you might capture it there itself and broadcast it.

Comment: C# server is used to schedule live broadcasts using youtube Data API and as a signaling server. How can I broadcast it using C# server? Doesn't C# server will have to establish P2P connections with all viewers of broadcast and send seperate streams to each of these viewers? If, that is the case, then it will put a huge load on our servers.